# Replacement of $1/\sin^2$ term in volume integral?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Another question from the Warren text, concerning a replacement Warren makes in a triple integral. I'll gladly include more context if asked, but I'll try to include what I feel is necessary here. 
Given the integral
$$ E = I_e {R^2F^2_T\over\omega\sin2\theta}\int\int\int{\sin^2\pi N_1p_1\over\sin^2\pi p_1}{\sin^2\pi N_2p_2\over\sin^2\pi p_2}{\sin^2\pi N_3p_3\over\sin^2\pi p_3} \space dV,$$
and rewriting the volume element $dV$ as 
$$dV = \lambda\mathbf{b}_1dp_1\cdot \lambda\mathbf{b}_2dp_2\times\lambda\mathbf{b}_3dp_3 = \lambda^3 v_b dp_1 dp_2 dp_3 = (\lambda^3/v_a)dp_1dp_2dp_3.$$
Warren then states that the integrand is only of interest for very small values of $p_1p_2p_3$, and proceeds to replace the denominators $\sin^2\pi p_i$ by $(\pi p_1)^2$, and takes the integrals from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, resulting in:
$$ E = I_e{R^2\lambda^3F^2_T\over\omega v_a\sin2\theta} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin^2\pi N_1p_1\over(\pi p_1)^2}dp_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin^2\pi N_2p_2\over(\pi p_2)^2}dp_2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin^2\pi N_3p_3\over(\pi p_3)^2}dp_3
.$$
Is this just a case of the functions being similar when restricted to small variables, and one being replaced by the other for the sake of ease of calculation? Or is there some true equivalence between the two functions? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \sin(x) $ and $ x $ are equal only when $ x = 0 $ otherwise they are different but in your example when $x$ is small enough, $x$ and $\sin(x)$ are almost equal and can be used interchangeably and this is the result of approximating Tailor series.